# Workflow to capture the modified date when there is a change in Comments column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am new to SharePoint designer. Is it possible to create a workflow which captures the modified date in a new column only when there is a change/edit happened in comments column. 
This workflow should not trigger if the comments column untouched. Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible directly with designer workflow .

Alternative way is

- Start work flow on item change
- Store your old comment in a dummy field.
- Then compare new comment with old comment
- If both are same stop work flow else continue